# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(x-x^2\ln\frac{1+x}{x}\right)$ with different methods gives different answers

Tags: limits

I was solving
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(x-x^2\ln\frac{1+x}{x}\right)$$
My first solution was:
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(x-x\ln(\frac{1+x}{x})^x\right) &= \lim_{x\to\infty} \left(x\left(1-\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{x}\right)^x\right)\right) \tag1\\[6pt]
&=\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(x\left(1-\ln(e)\right)\right) \\[6pt]
&=0 \tag2
\end{align}$$
Then I saw the right answer, which is $\frac{1}{2}$.
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(x-x^2\ln\frac{1+x}{x}\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{x}-\ln(\frac{1+x}{x})}{\frac{1}{x^2}} \tag3$$
Applying L'Hospital's rule:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{\frac{1+x}{x}}(-\frac{1}{x^2})}{-\frac{2}{x^3}}=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{2(1+x)}=\frac{1}{2}\tag4$$
I can not understand what's wrong with my first solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't remove your uncalculable symbol ln(e)=1 so you still have infinity times zero. Limit isn't finished

Comment: $lim_{x\to\infty} (x(1-\ln(\frac{1+x}{x})^x))=lim_{x\to\infty} (x(1-\ln(e))=0$ is wrong. It is like saying $\lim_{x \to \infty} x\frac  1 x=\lim_{x \to \infty} x (0)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrong result shows that **the following rule is wrong**:

If $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\ell$ then  $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)\ell$.

A simpler counterexample is:
$\lim_{x\to 0}x=0$ but $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1xx\ne\lim_{x\to a}\frac1x0.$$

Side remark: a less contrived solution than letting L'Hospital appear is using a short Taylor expansion:
$$\ln\left(1+\frac1x\right)=\frac1x-\frac1{2x^2}+o\left(\frac1{x^2}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

In order not to fall into pits of overly complex reasoning, look at the series at $x=0$ for $x\to \frac{1}{x}$

$$ x - x^2 \log \left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)|_{  x \to 1/x } \longrightarrow \frac{x-\log (x+1)}{x^2}= \frac{x-x +\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{3} \pm \dots}{x^2} $$

It is evident that the quadratic term survives for $x\to 0$